# Get the single post by id in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm actually working on project with Laravel and I understand how to get a collection of posts, but I'm kind of lost when I try to get just one single post by id if I want to use leftJoin.

I have a table called projects and groups. They have many to many relationship, so I also created pivot table called project_group.

This code will return a collection of the projects on the index page.

```
$projects = DB::table('projects as p')
            ->leftJoin('project_group as pb', 'pb.project_id', 'p.id')
                ->join('groups as g', 'g.id', 'pb.bodywork_id')
            ->select('p.*', 'g.*')
                ->orderBy('p.created_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate(10);
```

On single page I also want to use something like this, just to get only the project based on ID (primary key).

```
$project = Project::find($id)
```

Works fine, but without leftJoin, I can't acces the columns of other table. When I tried to use similar code as for the index page, it only worked with ->first() which gave me the first project ever created, but ->find($id) didn't worked and I'm confused what to do.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `find()` to get data only by primary key without other conditions like `Project::join('groups', 'groups.project_id','=', 'project.id')->find($id)`. In your situation you should use `first()` with `where()` condition in which you set your PK.
**For example:** 
`$project = Project::join('groups', 'groups.project_id','=', 'project.id')->where('project.id',$id)->first()`, where **id** is your PK.

Answer (score 0):

Laraval can handle [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship.
If you build your models and migrations  like this, you can use Model::find($id)

If you need help with code, i will append my answer.